# Add custom data attributes to Semantic UI Dropdown when items are retrieved via Ajax

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Here is how I was building my dropdown (in haml):

```
#my_dropdown.ui.dropdown{ data: { path: objects_path } }
  = f.hidden_field :my_id
  %i.dropdown.icon
  .default.text Text
  .menu
    - @collection.each do |object|
      .item{ data: { value: object.id, text: object.name, color: object.color } }
        = object.name
```

This was working great. My `.item` elements had extra data, such as `.data('color')`. I decided I wanted to switch to an ajax approach instead of loading all of the elements at once.

```
$.fn.api.settings.api =
    'search objects': $('#my_dropdown').data('path') + '?q={query}'

$('#my_dropdown').dropdown
    apiSettings:
      action: 'search objects'

    onChange: (value, text, selectedItem) ->
      console.log selectedItem.data()
```

Here is what my returned JSON looks like:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "results": [
    { "name":"Object #1", "value":1, "color":"blue" },
    { "name":"Object #2", "value":2, "color":"red" },
    { "name":"Object #3", "value":3, "color":"green" }
  ]
}
```

When I do the `console.log selectedItem.data()` after the dropdown select is changed, I only see:

```
{ value: 1 }
```

And the generated HTML looks like:

```
<div class="item" data-value="1">Object #1</div>
<div class="item" data-value="2">Object #2</div>
<div class="item" data-value="3">Object #3</div>
```

**How can I get the items to include the custom data attributes, such as `data-color` while using Ajax**?

Comment: the array with key `results` is missing all commas after each element

Comment: That was a typo while creating the question. I'll fix it though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to manually override the Semantic UI menu template with the following code:

```
$.fn.dropdown.settings.templates =
  menu: (response, fields) ->
    values = response[fields.values] or {}
    html = ''
    $.each values, (index, option) ->
      extraData = ''
      $.each fields.extraAttrs, (_j, attr) ->
        if option[attr]
          extraData += "data-#{attr}='" + option[attr] + "''"

      maybeText = if option[fields.text] then 'data-text="' + option[fields.text] + '"' else ''
      maybeDisabled = if option[fields.disabled] then 'disabled ' else ''
      html += '<div class="' + maybeDisabled + 'item" data-value="' + option[fields.value] + '"' + extraData + maybeText + '>'
      html += option[fields.name]
      html += '</div>'
      return
    html
```

Then when I'm initializing my dropdown, I can do:

```
$('#my_dropdown').dropdown
    apiSettings:
      action: 'search objects'
    fields:
      extraAttrs: ['color']
```

That allows me to access extra data elements on each of the dropdown items. If someone has a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could use for this case is that to save option value as can object. This solved my problem

JS

```
$(option).val(`{ id: '${item._id}', validTimestamp: ${validTimestamp} }`);
```

HTML

```
<div class="item" data-value="{ id: '61ccf18e9d865424e7e0dd89', validTimestamp: 7776000000 }">3 months</div>
```